# Handle windows message in Maui Windows using WinAPI

Tags: c#, winapi, maui

It is necessary to process the messages sent via the channel. In WPF, the code for processing messages is as follows:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow: Window 
{
    public MainWindow() {
      InitializeComponent();

      this.SourceInitialized += new EventHandler(OnSourceInitialized);
    }
    void OnSourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      HwndSource source = (HwndSource) PresentationSource.FromVisual(this);
      source.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(HandleMessages));
    }
    private static IntPtr HandleMessages(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) {
      //Handle messages here
      if (msg == 49900) {
        Debug.WriteLine(wParam);
        Debug.WriteLine(lParam);
      }

      return System.IntPtr.Zero;
    }
}
```

The message arrives, I process it. Everything works.

I'm trying to do the same in Maui for Windows. Analogues of AddHook and so on.. there is no, I do it through the Windows API.

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int hookType, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, IntPtr dwThreadId);

private static IntPtr SetHook(HookTypes typeOfHook, HookProc callBack, bool onThread = true) 
{
  //IntPtr hInstance = LoadLibrary("User32");
  ProcessModule module = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule;
  IntPtr hModule = GetModuleHandle(module.ModuleName);

  using(Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
  using(ProcessModule currentModule = currentProcess.MainModule) {
    if (onThread)
      return SetWindowsHookEx((int) typeOfHook, callBack, 0, GetCurrentThreadId());
    else
      return SetWindowsHookEx((int) typeOfHook, callBack, hModule, 0);
    //return SetWindowsHookEx((int)typeOfHook, callBack, GetModuleHandle(currentModule.ModuleName), 0);
  }
}

private static IntPtr HookCallback(IntPtr hwnd, uint message, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
  // Handle
  if (hwnd.ToInt32() == 49900) {
    Debug.WriteLine($ "{hwnd}{message} - {lParam} - {wParam}");
  }

  //_action?.Invoke(message);

  return IntPtr.Zero;
}

public static void RegisterWindowMessage(string lpString, Action < string > action) 
{
  _action = action;
  _msg = RegisterWindowMessage(lpString.ToString());

  HoockProc = new HookProc(HookCallback);
  /*
              ProcessModule module = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule;
              IntPtr hModule = GetModuleHandle(module.ModuleName);*/

  MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
    var WH_MSGFILTER = SetHook(HookTypes.WH_MSGFILTER, HoockProc);
    var WH_CALLWNDPROC = SetHook(HookTypes.WH_CALLWNDPROC, HoockProc);
    var WH_CALLWNDPROCRET = SetHook(HookTypes.WH_CALLWNDPROCRET, HoockProc);
    var WH_KEYBOARD = SetHook(HookTypes.WH_KEYBOARD, HoockProc);
    var WH_KEYBOARD_LL = SetHook(HookTypes.WH_KEYBOARD_LL, HoockProc, false);
    var WH_MOUSE = SetHook(HookTypes.WH_MOUSE, HoockProc);
    var WH_MOUSE_LL = SetHook(HookTypes.WH_MOUSE_LL, HoockProc, false);
    var WH_JOURNALRECORD = SetHook(HookTypes.WH_JOURNALRECORD, HoockProc, false); //
    var WH_JOURNALPLAYBACK = SetHook(HookTypes.WH_JOURNALPLAYBACK, HoockProc, false); //
    var WH_FOREGROUNDIDLE = SetHook(HookTypes.WH_FOREGROUNDIDLE, HoockProc);
    var WH_SYSMSGFILTER = SetHook(HookTypes.WH_SYSMSGFILTER, HoockProc, true); //
    var WH_GETMESSAGE = SetHook(HookTypes.WH_GETMESSAGE, HoockProc);
    var WH_CBT = SetHook(HookTypes.WH_CBT, HoockProc);
    var WH_HARDWARE = SetHook(HookTypes.WH_HARDWARE, HoockProc);
    var WH_DEBUG = SetHook(HookTypes.WH_DEBUG, HoockProc);
    var WH_SHELL = SetHook(HookTypes.WH_SHELL, HoockProc);
  });

}
```

IntPtr for these hooks is set:

[image]

I don't get a reply to the message. What I'm doing wrong? I take the correct window descriptor, I checked it through Spy++

Comment: Are you confident that `currentProcess.MainModule` identifies the module that contains the hook procedure code?

Comment: @IInspectable currentProcess.MainModule is not used

Comment: Right, but `module` is. Which is *literally* the same thing. The question still stands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with WinAPI by creating an empty invisible window inside Maui Blazor.

Code:

```cs
internal class Win32
    {
        public const uint WM_DESTROY = 0x0002;
        public const uint WM_CREATE = 0x0001;
        public const uint WM_PAINT = 0x000F;

        public const uint WS_OVERLAPPED = 0x00000000;
        public const uint WS_MAXIMIZEBOX = 0x00010000;
        public const uint WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x00020000;
        public const uint WS_THICKFRAME = 0x00040000;
        public const uint WS_SYSMENU = 0x00080000;
        public const uint WS_CAPTION = 0x00C00000;
        public const uint WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000;
        public const uint WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW = WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX;

        public const uint IDI_APPLICATION = 32512;

        public const uint IDC_ARROW = 32512;

        public const uint COLOR_WINDOW = 5;

        public const uint MB_OK = 0x00000000;
        public const uint MB_ICONEXCLAMATION = 0x00000030;
        public const uint MB_SETFOREGROUND = 0x00010000;

        //public const uint CW_USEDEFAULT = 0x80000000;

        public delegate IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        /*
        public enum GetWindowLongConst
        {
            GWL_WNDPROC = (-4),
            GWL_HINSTANCE = (-6),
            GWL_HWNDPARENT = (-8),
            GWL_STYLE = (-16),
            GWL_EXSTYLE = (-20),
            GWL_USERDATA = (-21),
            GWL_ID = (-12)
        }
         * */

        [Flags]
        public enum ClassStyles : uint
        {
            ByteAlignClient = 0x1000,
            ByteAlignWindow = 0x2000,
            ClassDC = 0x40,
            DoubleClicks = 0x8,
            DropShadow = 0x20000,
            GlobalClass = 0x4000,
            HorizontalRedraw = 0x2,
            NoClose = 0x200,
            OwnDC = 0x20,
            ParentDC = 0x80,
            SaveBits = 0x800,
            VerticalRedraw = 0x1
        }

        public enum MessageBoxResult : uint
        {
            Ok = 1,
            Cancel,
            Abort,
            Retry,
            Ignore,
            Yes,
            No,
            Close,
            Help,
            TryAgain,
            Continue,
            Timeout = 32000
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct POINT
        {
            public int X;
            public int Y;

            public POINT(int x, int y)
            {
                X = x;
                Y = y;
            }
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct SIZE
        {
            public int cx;
            public int cy;

            public SIZE(int cx, int cy)
            {
                this.cx = cx;
                this.cy = cy;
            }
        }

        public struct MSG
        {
            public IntPtr hwnd;
            public uint message;
            public IntPtr wParam;
            public IntPtr lParam;
            public uint time;
            public POINT pt;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct PAINTSTRUCT
        {
            public IntPtr hdc;
            public bool fErase;
            public RECT rcPaint;
            public bool fRestore;
            public bool fIncUpdate;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 32)]
            public byte[] rgbReserved;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct RECT
        {
            public int left, top, right, bottom;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct WNDCLASSEX
        {
            public uint cbSize;
            public ClassStyles style;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]
            public WndProc lpfnWndProc;
            public int cbClsExtra;
            public int cbWndExtra;
            public IntPtr hInstance;
            public IntPtr hIcon;
            public IntPtr hCursor;
            public IntPtr hbrBackground;
            public string lpszMenuName;
            public string lpszClassName;
            public IntPtr hIconSm;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern sbyte GetMessage(out MSG lpMsg, IntPtr hWnd, uint wMsgFilterMin,
           uint wMsgFilterMax);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr DispatchMessage(ref MSG lpmsg);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool TranslateMessage(ref MSG lpMsg);

        //[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowLong")]       // 32 bits only
        //public static extern IntPtr GetWindowLongPtr(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr BeginPaint(IntPtr hwnd, out PAINTSTRUCT lpPaint);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool EndPaint(IntPtr hWnd, ref PAINTSTRUCT lpPaint);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern void PostQuitMessage(int nExitCode);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr DefWindowProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint uMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr LoadCursor(IntPtr hInstance, int lpCursorName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr LoadIcon(IntPtr hInstance, IntPtr lpIconName);


        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern MessageBoxResult MessageBox(IntPtr hWnd, string text, string caption, int options);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateWindowEx(
           uint dwExStyle,
           string lpClassName,
           string lpWindowName,
           uint dwStyle,
           int x,
           int y,
           int nWidth,
           int nHeight,
           IntPtr hWndParent,
           IntPtr hMenu,
           IntPtr hInstance,
           IntPtr lpParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern short RegisterClassEx(ref WNDCLASSEX lpwcx);

        //[DllImport("gdi.dll")]
        //public static extern bool GetTextExtentPoint(IntPtr hdc, string lpString, int cbString, out SIZE lpSize);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern uint RegisterWindowMessage(string lpString);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern bool TextOut(IntPtr hdc, int nXStart, int nYStart,
           string lpString, int cbString);

        //[DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        //public static extern bool GetTextMetrics(IntPtr hdc, out TEXTMETRIC lptm);
    }

    internal static class WindowExtensions
    {

        #region Private static fields

        private static Action<nint> _action;
        private static uint _msgId;

        #endregion

        private static readonly string AppName = "DrawHello Program";
        private static readonly string ClassName = "DrawHelloClass";
        private static IntPtr hWnd;

        #region Public methods

        public static void RegisterWindowMessage(string lpString, Action<nint> action)
        {
            _action = action;
            _msgId = Win32.RegisterWindowMessage(lpString.ToString());

            WNDCLASSEX wcex = new()
            {
                style = ClassStyles.DoubleClicks
            };
            wcex.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(wcex);
            wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
            wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
            wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
            //wcex.hIcon = Win32.LoadIcon(IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)Win32.IDI_APPLICATION);
            //wcex.hCursor = Win32.LoadCursor(IntPtr.Zero, (int)Win32.IDC_ARROW);
            wcex.hIconSm = IntPtr.Zero;
            //wcex.hbrBackground = (IntPtr)(Win32.COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
            wcex.lpszMenuName = null;
            wcex.lpszClassName = ClassName;
       
            if (RegisterClassEx(ref wcex) == 0)
            {
                _ = MessageBox(IntPtr.Zero, "RegisterClassEx failed", AppName,
                    (int)(MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_SETFOREGROUND));
                return;
            }

            //uint visible = Win32.WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | Win32.WS_VISIBLE;
            uint invisible = 0;

            var x = 0; // 250;
            var y = 0; // 250;
            var w = 0; // 250;
            var h = 0; // 250;
            hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, ClassName, AppName, invisible,
                x, y, w, h, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

            if (hWnd == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                _ = MessageBox(IntPtr.Zero, "CreateWindow failed", AppName, (int)(Win32.MB_OK | Win32.MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | Win32.MB_SETFOREGROUND));
                return;
            }

            // Main message loop:
            /*int rv;
            while ((rv = GetMessage(out MSG Msg, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0)) > 0)
            {
                _ = Win32.TranslateMessage(ref Msg);
                _ = Win32.DispatchMessage(ref Msg);
            }*/
        }

        private static IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint message, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (message == _msgId)
            {
                _action?.Invoke(lParam);
            }
            switch (message)
            {
                case WM_DESTROY:
                    PostQuitMessage(0);
                    return IntPtr.Zero;
                default:
                    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```